# SQL query with subquery equivalent for Linq-to-SQL

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I rewrite again my question, I didn't expose it in the right way, sorry.

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.documentNumber
FROM TABLE1 T1      
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON      
    T2.documentNumber = (
        SELECT TOP 1 documentNumber         
        FROM TABLE2  
        WHERE description = T1.description)                                     
WHERE T1.color = 'RED';
```

I need to retrieve all the rows in `T1` filtered by color with the corresponding `T2.documentNumber` value, but unique `T1` rows, I mean, a relation 1 to 1 with `T2`.

`T1` and `T2` are related through `description` column. Because `description` is not unique in `t2`, this table can contain N rows with the same description, since I want only 1 row as result for each `T1` row, I get the top 1 filtering by the unique column (`documentNumber`).

This query works fine for me, want I need to know is the equivalent for Linq-to-SQL, I tried for several hours but without success. Could please somebody help me?

Comment: What column do T1 and T2 have in common?

Comment: T1 and T2 are related through "description"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var result = table1.Where(t1 => t1.color == "RED")
                   .GroupJoin(table2,
                              t1 => t1.description,
                              t2 => t2.description,
                              (t1,g) => new {
                                              T1 = t1,
                                              DocumentNumber = g.FirstOrDefault()
                                             });
```

Mandatory 101 link: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b should help deal with these sort of queries....

Comment: I need to leave the office right now, let me check it tomorrow and I give you feedback. Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't resist the temptation and I remained in the office, I tried it and it works as expected, that was what I need, thanks a lot! you saved my day.

Comment: @Jero Coolios, but do have a look at the examples though, something like this should be apparent just from the definitions of the Queryable extension methods.